Automate USSD codes on Android
Device: Samsung Galaxy S24
Android: 14
One UI: 6.1
I need to schedule USSD code (like *101*4# and press Call) for extra gigabytes every month. But it's required to send it at 23-00 on planned date to work correctly without extra payment.
I have found some Andoid Studio solutions for Java developers, but I haven't experience in it.
Is there some way with user options on Android OS or some application to download for scheduling with calls?

For non-developers there are tools like Tasker and IFTTT which allow to define tasks via UI and then run them if certain conditions are met. Not sure If these tools support USSD codes on your system.

Any automation app can easily perform such tasks, try Automate (free) with its USSD request block.
